# How to display custom text in ios wifi settings

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, wifi, settings

I have a very specific question in programming an ios app.

In general when you open your ios wifi settings, there should be a list of available networks to choose.. so far..

now I want that in some cases, if a network meets specific requirements, a text is diplayed down below the network name (e.g. like "connect with WIFIAPP") and by clicking on the network you open the "WIFIAPP"..

Is there any possibility to do that and if yes, how? A framework or something like that?

Hope you guys understand my concern..

Thank you for any help!

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are after is implemented by the [`NEHotspotHelper`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nehotspothelper) class in the Network Extension Framework.  In order to use this class you need to complete a [questionnaire](https://developer.apple.com/contact/network-extension) and be authorised by Apple.

More details are included in the [Hotspot Network Subsystem Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/Hotspot_Network_Subsystem_Guide/Contents/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016639), but essentially your app runs in the background and takes part in the network scanning process. It can provide an annotation for recognised networks and the user can invoke your app from Settings in order to complete the network authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, access to wifi network parameters is completely closed from developers. From your app you can only tell apart if device is closed to wifi or 3G cellular network. Nothing more. I don't even say about native Settings app. You can do only some extra limited things outside of your app, like play music, or show your custom Widget.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! But are you really sure about that? The app Instabridge does quite the same thing and it works well.. but i still dont know how they did this..

Comment: You can look up Reachability framework, and look at its API. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39204 here is just the first discussion on developer.apple forum that I found

Comment: Well, I know that you cant display the list with your available networks in your app.. that is the reason why I asked here to do it vice versa. So that you call the app in your ios settings..

Comment: OK, I see. Nonetheless, the answer stays the same.

Comment: i see this also with the "telekom manager" (an app in germany for telekom hotspot customers)